# AddThis Inline share buttons <javascript> not shown in webpage

Tags: javascript, html, addthis

I searched for other answers but mine seems the simplest!

My web builder lets me insert Javascript, HTML or CSS snippets into the `<head>` and `<body>` source code. It seems these snippets affect all website pages.

I inserted **AddThis 'inline share buttons'** within the `<body>`:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="//s7.addthis.com/js/300/addthis_widget.js#pubid=ra-5ebdd74910cfe8a0"></script>
```

For activating the buttons, I added the next code in a single web page (drag-and-drop html code tool):

```
<div class="addthis_inline_share_toolbox_xa65"></div>
```

But the share buttons are not shown on that page: **http://builder.ferozo.com/reparando-todo/#!/-testing/**

I've tried adding both code snippets together into the same web page but no results. It doesn't seem to be a problem related to browsers blocking an unsafe widget due to a lack of a SSL Certificate.

Any idea of what could be the problem?

Comment: What is the purpose?

Comment: Social one-clic buttons for sharing the web page on Facebook, What's App, Gmail, etc.